# What are the JQuery Plugin have to add for Islamic Date Picker Calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to pick the date using Jquery Date picker. I download the file from [Keith-wood.name](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html). It has so many js files and css files. It makes me confuse. So I set the Jquery as mentioned in that page. But It doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.calendars.plus.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.calendars.islamic.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHijriDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <script>
            $('#txtHijriDate').calendarsPicker(
            {
                monthsToShow: [2, 3], showOtherMonths: true,
                onSelect: function (date) { alert('You picked ' + date[0].formatDate()); }
            });

            $('#pickerButton').click(function () {
                try {
                    var calendar = $.calendars.instance($('#pickerCal').val());
                    $('#defaultPicker').calendarsPicker('option', { calendar: calendar }).
                        calendarsPicker('showMonth', parseInt($('#pickerYear').val(), 10),
                        parseInt($('#pickerMonth').val(), 10));
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look at the console.

> It throws error on `Cannot read property 'regionalOptions' of undefined jquery.calendars.plus.min.js` and
>
> `Cannot read property 'baseCalendar' of undefined  jquery.calendars.islamic.min.js`

Comment: That is because you have not loaded the original plugin: `jquery.calendars.js`.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization read this

Comment: @AlfinPaul how to change the month of arabic and year with jquery-ui

Comment: @mohamedfaiz update the code below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with you, docs on [keith-wood.name](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html) is a bit complex and confusing.

If you take a look at the **Usage** section of [jQuery Calendars Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html) page, you will see that you need to import the following files:

- `jquery.min.js` - the jQuery library
- `jquery.calendars.js`
- `jquery.calendars.plus.js`
- `jquery.plugin.js`
- `jquery.calendars.picker.js`
- and `jquery.calendars.picker.css` (default style)

If you have to show an Islamic/Hijri calendar, you have to add the `jquery.calendars.islamic.min.js` file and add `calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic')` option in the `calendarsPicker` function.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#txtHijriDate').calendarsPicker({
  calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'),
  monthsToShow: [2, 3],
  showOtherMonths: true,
  onSelect: function (date) {
    alert('You picked ' + date[0].formatDate());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.plus.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/js/jquery.calendars.islamic.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/css/jquery.calendars.picker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="txtHijriDate">
```

**Additional notes:**

If you have to localize your Islamic calendar you can add `jquery.calendars.islamic-ar.js` (Arabic localisation) or `jquery.calendars.islamic-fa.js` (Farsi/Persian localisation).

If you need to customize datepicker's style take a look at the *Layout/Style* tab of [this page](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html), it shows how to add one of the provided themes (e.g. `redmond.calendars.picker.css`) and how they work together with jQuery UI themes.

Answer (score 3):

visit [Datepicker Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and go to localization and see various options

Also see [official working example](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)

In page add this js which is for localization

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>`

and in snippet see how to initialize language

```js
$(function() {
  $('#adverts_eventDate').datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['ar'], { //initialize language
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  }));
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="adverts_eventDate" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Please visit this page](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)

From the drop-down list near words 'Select a date from a popup or inline calendar' - chose 'Arabic'. If functionality that it provides out-of box is ok for your goal - then perhaps I could give some instructions how to install it. ^_^ If islamic dates require more tweaks and complex rules - then my answer would be useless.

connect there libraries in your page in this order:

1. jQuery
2. jQuertUI
3. jquery.ui.datepicker-ar.js

after that you can use arabic localization. You invoke it in a place where you left your

**do this way**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ar" ] );
 });
```

**datepicker input**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: I check your code. It's working, but after i select the date, it's automatically convert into english calander. In my case it should display arabic calander only

Answer (score 1):

Please go to this link of codepen. Use this javascript code. It is very simple and lightweight Islamic date picker. Lightweight Datepicker for Gregorian Hijri Calendar Converter  [  https: //codepen.io/zulns/pen/adqQjq ]